# Rspec stubbed finder finds an enumerable instead of single object

Tags: rspec2

I am just getting started with rspec 2 and having trouble, I think, somewhere in one of my method stubs.  I am trying to test the 'show' action from my clients_controller.rb, but it fails, returning an Enumerable::Enumerator instead of an object.  The 'index' action works fine.  My goal is to make sure the currently logged in user can view his or her clients, but not any other user's clients.

```
before_filter :require_user

def index
  @clients = current_user.clients
end
def show
  @client = current_user.clients.find(params[:id])
end
```

with:

```
before :each do
  stub_current_user
  @my_client = mock_model(Client, :user_id => @current_user.id)
  @not_my_client = mock_model(Client, :user_id => @current_user.id + 1)
  @current_user.stub!(:clients) { @clients = [@my_client] }
  @clients.stub!(:find){ @my_client }
end

describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns the current user's clients as @clients" do
    get :index
    assigns(:clients).should eq([@my_client])
  end
end

describe "GET show" do
  it "assigns the requested client as @client if @client is the current user's client" do
    get :show, :id => @my_client.id
    assigns(:client).should eq(@my_client)
  end

  it "does not assign the requested client if @client is not the current user's client" do
    get :show, :id => @not_my_client.id
    assigns(:client).should == nil
  end
end
```

stub_current_user is in spec_helpers.rb:

```
def stub_current_user
  @current_user = mock_model(User, :name => 'Bob Johnson', :email => 'bob@johnson.com', 
                                   :role => "account_holder", :incomplete_subscription? => false, 
                                   :plan => mock_model(Plan, :client_limit => 5),
                                   :monthly_rate => 100)
  if defined?(controller) # for controller specs
    controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@current_user)
  elsif defined?(template) # for view specs
    template.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@current_user)
  else
    'wat'
  end
end
```

The test of the 'index' action passes, but both tests of the 'show' action fail, with these errors:

```
1) ClientsController GET show assigns the requested client as @client if @client is the current user's client
 Failure/Error: assigns(:client).should eq(@my_client)

 expected #<Client:0x81b67840 @name="Client_1007">
      got #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x1036471d0>

 (compared using ==)

 Diff:
 @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 -#<Client:0x81b67840 @name="Client_1007">
 +#<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x1036471d0>
 # ./spec/controllers/clients_controller_spec.rb:31

2) ClientsController GET show does not assigns the requested client if @client is not the current user's client
 Failure/Error: assigns(:client).should == nil
 expected: nil,
      got: #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x1035336b8> (using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/clients_controller_spec.rb:39
```

I am not sure if I am going wrong in the mocks, the tests themselves, or somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Does the record with `@current_user.id + 1` exist?

Comment: @Zabba, no it doesn't.  I tried (just now) stubbing it in the before :each block with `@other_user = mock_model(User, :id => @current_user.id + 1)` and changing @not_my_client to `@not_my_client = mock_model(Client, :user_id => @other_user.id)`
But it still gave the same errors.  Thanks for the pointer though!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it's returning enumerable is because Rails 3 doesn't load all of the records when you call the clients association, instead it returns enumerable, so it can be more efficient with memory.  Essentially you've got fake database cursors.  I'm not sure how you would solve this, but this should at least answer your question about what's going wrong.

You might try this though:

```
get :index
assigns(:clients).to_a.should eq([@my_client])
```